Grapevine post request issue
I am using the Grapevine server in a console application.
Calls via get work perfectly.
Now I want to pass a serialized order object to an endpoint via post request, but I get the following error message:

Sent 0 request content bytes, but Content-Length promised 538

Server code (empty body):
    [RestResource]
    public class OrderService {

    public OrderService() { }

    [RestRoute(HttpMethod = HttpMethod.POST, PathInfo = "/distribution/saveorder")]
    public IHttpContext SaveOrder(IHttpContext context) {
      
        return context;
    }
}

Client code:
public void Test() {

    RestClient client = new RestClient();
    client.Host = "localhost";
    client.Port = 8120;
    RestRequest request = new RestRequest("/distribution/saveorder");
    request.HttpMethod = HttpMethod.POST;
    request.ContentType = ContentType.JSON;

    Order order = new ();
    order.Buyer.Number = "4711";
    OrderItem item = new ();
    item.Article.Number = "1111111";
    item.Quantity = 5;
    order.Items.Add (item);
    item = new ();
    item.Article.Number = "2222222";
    item.Quantity = 20;
 
    request.Payload = JsonSerializer.Serialize(order);

    request.ContentLength = request.Payload.Length;
    var response = client.Execute(request);
}

The error message is pretty clear, but where / how do I enter the content length - or am I using the payload incorrectly?

As the maintainer of Grapevine, I would recommend abandoning any use of the RestRequest class in favor of FluentHttpClient, of which I am also the maintainer. Newer versions of Grapevine do not include the RestRequest class at all.
Sending a request to your endpoint with FluentHttpClient using the provided information would look like this:
public async Task Test()
{
    // Create your order object
    var order = new Order();

    var client = new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:8120") };

    var response = await client.UsingRoute("/distribution/saveorder")
        .WithJsonContent(order)
        .PostAsync();

    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        // Do something with the response
    }
    else
    {
        // Interrogate the response for the error
    }
}

